# 6 character edit minimum when it is a code edit that materially changes the program

Tags: feature-request

[run R script from .bat (batch file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811871/run-r-script-from-bat-batch-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Here there is a simple mistake, where the second `arg1` should be `arg2`. Is there a good reason I should be prevented from doing this?
If its less than 6 characters, I understand not wanting to bump the question or award rep for an edit that small, but why not just disable those features for less-than-6-character edits, rather than disallowing them completely? For now I'm left with the choice of rigging a 6 character change or leaving inaccurate code, neither of which seem appropriate.

All of the current questions about the minimum are talking about spellchecking. This is more important.

Perhaps if a change is made in a code block it could be treated differently?

Comment: +1, Good idea. I've edited that answer for you.

Comment: This is not strictly a duplicate.  It is a question about a real problem I have seen several times on SO.  Someone answers a question with a code-snippet that doesn't actually work because it has a syntax or logical error in it.  The fix is often small, below the 6-chars requirement so it gets rejected. A recent case in point is http://stackoverflow.com/a/3427519/1296044 which uses `LDD_PRELOAD` (incorrect) instead of `LD_PRELOAD`.  How can we enable good caring editors to fix these errors?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it's important edits versus minor beaufitying edits! To fix an answer to my question I needed to add 4 quotes to the line of code to avoid getting errors from filesnames with spaces. Only 4 chars so I added a line: "Note the double quotes added…" that I think just added clutter to the answer. Unless it was tried it was unlikely that the problem would be seen. Why the limit? Lots of <6 char vandalism? it's easy to add 2 or 3 more chars with bad intent. Points? Didn't know you got them for an edit nor care; I'd go with 0 points for < 6 chars or lower the needed rep.