# What can I do when an edit is wrong, and then I am stuck with the six-characters limit?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, editing-help

I asked a question and got [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780956/how-to-get-the-context-of-a-search-in-beautifulsoup/28781221#28781221).

When I ran the answer though my test code I noticed that the last line is not the one I actually get (it must have been a typo as the answer itself is absolutely correct).

I edited the answer to include the actual output for the code (which starts with the tag strong). Bam, the code got interpreted even though it was indented as code.

I then desperately tried to modify my edit to make the right code appear - but I am stuck with the six-characters limit. This is not a trivial edit; it completely changes the output.

What should I do in such cases, short of flagging 'Help! Help!'?

(And as a side note: how do I make the code appear non-interpreted?)

Comment: Leave a comment to the original poster of the answer explaining the problem, and perhaps they (or another user who isn't subject to the 6-char limit) will fix it. At the least, future readers will see the comment. (Or you could find more in the post to fix, like spelling or punctuation or grammar or formatting, that will get to 6 characters. It's typically not hard to do.)

Comment: This is what I did. Another aspect of the problem is that I may be able to find more than six characters to change once, but now that I tried twice to make the code appear correctly there i snot much I can do.

Comment: Even though the answer by Bergi's a great hack, I took the lazy way around and waited for 2k rep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [6 character edit minimum when it is a code edit that materially changes the program](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275090/6-character-edit-minimum-when-it-is-a-code-edit-that-materially-changes-the-prog)

Comment: This limit is ridiculous. I shouldn't have to hack around the limit or bother the original author to change 'http' to 'https', as an example, when it materially affects the answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A hack to work around the six-character limit is to add an HTML-style comment to the post text:

```
<!-- six-character limit workaround -->
```

> how do I make the code appear non-interpreted?

If you mean the syntax-highlighting, you can disable that by prefixing the code snippet by [`<!-- language: lang-none -->`](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).
To counter HTML parsing, you can use entities like `&gt;` and `&lt;`: <strong>

Comment: Note that any reviewer worth the title will pick up on this, and click on 'improve edit' to remove this comment.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker not everyone views markdown comparison. I like to use rendered preview with markdown when I can't see the difference

Comment: Sometimes, unfortunately, the rules on this site need to be worked around - good answer.

Comment: I would reject this edit...

Comment: Why bother with the 6 character limit if it is trivial to work around?

Comment: @Phil maybe it's there to inhibit moronic vandalisms, as morons can't do trivial things by definition?

Comment: @Phil Implementing annoying mechanics that have trivial workarounds is sort of the SE way. You'll learn to love it, it's part of the charm.

Comment: @Phil: It's only trivial when you know it. (Admittedly I didn't expect the question to gain such popularity). It should definitely only be used for non-trivial edits, anyone who uses this for trivial changes should be banned by the reviewers.

Comment: @CBauer Are you saying you would reject based purely on the character count being worked around, no matter what the edit is? The count restriction is there because a machine check can't do much better than that;  human reviewers ought to be more capable.

Comment: @CBauer: No, I would reject iff it was a minor edit (not really necessary) that goes below the 6 character count; the limit is there for a reason.

Comment: You should explain in the edit reason that the change, even though minor in terms of the number of characters changed, is essential for the answer to be correct.

Comment: Agree bergi. If the edit is trivial and unnecessary I would reject. The example was vague. Also if you can't find 6 characters to change to improve a stack overflow post, you're in a very lucky minority :)

Comment: This is abusive.

Answer (score -4):

Building on the answer of Bergi I would recommend

```
<!-- 
    six-character limit workaround as recommended in
    https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287141/333403

     Editors: Please remove this comment.
-->
```

This makes the reasoning behind the comment more transparent.