# Editing a broken link with less than 6 characters changed

Tags: discussion, support, broken-link

I want to edit a broken link in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9887904/682673) but the new working link is only a few characters different to the original one:

Old link: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

New link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

SO won't let me make the edit because it falls under the 6 character limit for edits. What's the best thing to do here? Flag it? Or add to the bottom of the answer explaining the edit so it passes the character limit?

Comment: It's not the *only* thing you could change in that post!

Comment: It is really silly that the "solution" to these types of questions is to come up with edits that change more characters. I mean, seriously? OTOH once you hit 2000 reputation you can make edits without review, so there's that.

Comment: @neuronet I agree. There should be an exception to the rule for fixing broken links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick workaround that works well for links (better than [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287141/1048572)) is to inline it:

```
… with [realpath][1] or …

 [1]: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php
```

becomes

```
… with [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) or …
```

> What's the best thing to do here?

Don't use a flag for this kind of stuff. Put a comment beneath that post, usually the author will then change the link and thank you for the hint, at least when he is still active.
In general, it is of course better to bypass the six-character limit by fixing more things like misspellings or grammatical issues, but this is not always applicable.

Comment: I had another look at the answer after @Jongware commented. Spotted a couple grammatical errors so I fixed those and passed the limit. Nice idea though, I'll be sure to remember that for future edits