# Submitting edits with less than 6 characters

Tags: discussion, edits

Note that this is not a duplicate of [What is the reason behind the 6 character minimum for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251580/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-6-character-minimum-for-suggested-edits) as I'm aware *why* there is a minimum 6 character edit limit.

So I have this editing review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11857434

this is now probably going to be rejected as my attempts of working around the 6 character limit make it look weird and this didn't appear on the preview (I thought the empty spaces just get filtered out as they didn't count to the character count).

Now, I am pretty sure my edit (changing the documentation link from Russian to English) actually makes sense. While starting to wonder (after submitting the edit) I found those two questions, suggesting workarounds for the 6 character limit:

[Editing a broken link with less than 6 characters changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289278/editing-a-broken-link-with-less-than-6-characters-changed)

[What to do when an edit is wrong, and then I am stuck with the six-characters limit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287090/what-to-do-when-an-edit-is-wrong-and-then-i-am-stuck-with-the-six-characters-li?lq=1)

Now my question is: if we have (at least) two workarounds which seem to be more or less accepted, why is there still the minimum 6 character editing rule as the workarounds speak against the reasons of having at least 6 characters?

The reasons in my first linked questions were:

- Suggested edits make work for others

in this case, my suggested edit makes even more work because of the workaround, since there's more to "think" about it.

- We want to encourage people to make substantial edits

in this case, my edit just got bloated and worse than if I just changed those two characters (RU => EN)

What would have been the correct way in this case?

I would like to note again, that I'm not looking for further workarounds.

Comment: The idea behind the edit (linking to EN docs) is good, and there's indeed not much more that can be improved. The linked workarounds... "Work", but aren't really encouraged to be used. The best you can really do is to comment, suggesting the modification to the author of the Q/A. That said, the edit has been applied now.

Comment: As explained in the earlier question, correct way is to wait until you have 2k reputation and do those small edits after that. You can also write a comment describing what needs to be edited.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen Sadly 2k reputation does not become reality by waiting. And it might be hard to remember those changes then if you get that reputation. And for community it would be better to have the fixes sooner, so I do not consider that the right way.

Comment: Maybe it would make sense that small edits be allowed for posting/ reviewing, just not eligible for generating the editor rep. Some users are editing solely for the purpose bettering the overall user experience on stack overflow. To this end, I believe that all edits are  equal in importance. A single misspelled word has the potential to destroy the credibility of the poster, and thereby an entire post.

Comment: CONTD.We've all likely come across a post, at some time, where the poster was obviously knew what he/she was talking about,  but because English was not their first language,  their post ended up  getting downvoted by the community. I, for one, would like to see these threads  treated  as  documentation  or  historical documents, and maintained as such. community Taking away points generation will keep the feature from being abused while still letting us mold each post to it's potential.