# Adding code blocks to a question with less than 6 characters

Tags: discussion

So, I was viewing this question today [add a class to a div checking for children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005301/add-a-class-to-a-div-checking-for-children/50005732?noredirect=1#comment87028105_50005732) when I spotted an answer that needed a little editing. It wasn't terrible, it just needed code blocks added around their example. Not a major thing, and there weren't many more edits needed. There's a similar question here [Submitting edits with less than 6 characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320274/submitting-edits-with-less-than-6-characters) that poses a similar problem but slightly different.

When I tried to submit the edit, I was hit with the *more than 6 characters* warning as technically, I hadn't added or removed characters.

My question is, is it possible to have the 4 spaces required to initiate a code block count in the character changed check or is there a workaround for this that I've missed?

Comment: An edit that you raise has to be reviewed by other users before being approved and applied. Therefore, it's not worth using up other people's valuable reviewer time for an edit smaller than 6 characters. There's not much that can be done with that small a change to improve the overall quality. There were also more changes to that question that should have been made to improve quality, which have now been done by another user.

Comment: @EthanField Makes sense, although in this case I think that wrapping their code in a code block definitely improves the readability of the answer.

Comment: @EthanField None that I could have done with my reputation unfortunately, as looking at the edit review, it was spelling corrections and adding the previously mentioned code blocks.

Comment: @duplode Ah, thank you. I'd spotted the spelling mistake and used the '{ }' icon to wrap the code in a block but still didn't hit the 6 characters - due to whitespace not counting I suppose. I didn't spot the others. Also, thanks for the good advice. I'll do that in future.

Comment: (Reposting without misinformation): The advice in related Meta questions still applies: try to find further improvements that would bring the edit above the limit (in this case, I found a typo, a missing comma and missing inline code formatting for an identifier, which added three more characters). If that is not enough, let it be: odds are that a 2k+ user, not bound by the limit, will take care of it.

Comment: By the way, if you can't do the edit yourself, it is also appropriate to suggest it to the OP, as you have done. (That is what even 2k+ users ordinarily do when it comes to edits that go beyond trivialities like typos, grammar, formatting, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When users gain more than 2k reputation, they earn the power to make edits that are less than 6 characters.

Why is this? Because users under 2k reputation and guests can suggest edits to questions or answers, edits which have to go through an approval process. The suggested edits queue has all those suggested edits, and those edits aren't applied until enough people have agreed that the edit looks good. Likewise, the reviewers in the suggested edits queue can reject the edit if it does not help the post.

The suggested edits queue is already really busy, with hundreds or thousands of edits being approved each day, depending on how busy any given day is. In order to help reduce the burden on reviewers, a couple things are in place: The suggested edits queue gets capped at [500 suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) (used to be 200 but was [raised last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351727/how-come-the-suggested-edits-queue-can-suddenly-become-so-big/351728#351728)). Also, very minor edits are restricted from the queue. This is to encourage the edits going into the suggested queue to be meaningful edits -- meaning an edit that's worth the time to review. For more information why 6 characters was picked, [see this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251580/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-6-character-minimum-for-suggested-edits). This means that minor edits, like just adding some spaces,  changing just one word, etc, aren't allowed in the queue. If someone wants to make an edit that's so small, they need the permission to bypass the queue, either by having >2k rep or by being the post author.

So what can you do? Look for more things to improve in the post! More often than not, when a user doesn't know to use code blocks, there are a couple of other things wrong. I generally look for: Did the user include superfluous language (Greetings, thanks, etc.) that can be removed? Are there any typos or awkward phrases? Is there any excessive use of **bold** or other formatting tools or CAPS LOCK that should be toned down? In the case of a question, can the title be made more clear to reflect the body? More often than not, the answer to at least one of these is "Yes!", so fix that, and lo and behold, you're above the 6 character limit!

So what's left to address in your question is: Should the 4 spaces required to initiate a code block count in the character changed check? My answer is No. When suggesting edits to a post, look for more things to do, that way we aren't filling up the queue with small scale edits. If the only error is that the user didn't format the code block, and the rest of the answer looks great, then here's the work around that I would use: Leave a comment for the user telling them how to use the code blocks. That way, they learn for next time and will know to format their own code from now on.

Comment: I've passed the rep bar so I could edit at will ... but I am unable to point out a single fault in your answer. Well done.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I can see the rationale behind what you're saying - and it makes a lot of sense.