# Unable to edit a misspelled author name

Tags: support, edits

I tried to fix "Martin Flowers" to "Martin Fowler", and was unable to do it due to an "Edit should be at least 6 characters long" error message.

[AngularJS: Understanding design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286917/angularjs-understanding-design-pattern/30745329#30745329)

What can be done about it?

Comment: Well you can leave a comment.  The answerer was last seen 21 hours ago so there is a good chance they will see it and edit it.

Comment: Alternative, find other things in that massive answer that can be improved.  You can almost always find a grammatical or structural problem that you can fix to pass the minimum character count.

Comment: Curl up in a small ball with a bucket of ice cream, cry, drown in box wine, I dunno...

Comment: @Will Very helpful, that's what i'll do. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed. Didn't want you to lose any sleep over it.

Comment: Aww, now what will I do with all this ice cream and box wine?

Comment: Oh thx. Great. I'm putting my sleeping pills back to the drawer. Maybe it would be beneficial to get rid of the "six letters"  rule and there would be no need for these discussions... I really don't see how there may be any harm if someone makes an edit which is less then 6 characters...

Comment: Ah sorry this point has been made before http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits

Comment: The larger question is, *who is this Martin Flowers* and what has he done with the gang of four?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287141/2751851

Comment: (On the other hand, considering that the restriction [goes away once one hits 2k rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/242059), it is debatable whether outright hacking around the limit, as opposed to looking for reasons to make a larger edit or just leaving a comment, is really necessary.)

Comment: Flowers are great and shouldn't be edited